# Where in my code should I put BLoC builder and can I have more of them?

Tags: flutter

So I am trying to learn BLoC pattern and apply it to my weather app. The thing is the UI is kinda big, there are a lot of Columns and Rows. So I'm confused about where to put BlocBuilder.
Or maybe this whole Container should be returned by one BLoC event? This is basically the main and only screen of the app for now.

```
    class WeatherMainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: kBackgroundColor,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: 30,
                top: 15,
                left: 30,
                right: 30,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Today 28. apr',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: kAccentColor,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          MenuSearchButton(
                            boxSize: 60,
                            onPressed: () => print('search pressed'),
                            content: Icon(
                              Icons.search,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 30,
                            ),
                          ),
                          MenuSearchButton(
                            boxSize: 60,
                            onPressed: () => print('menu pressed'),
                            content: Icon(
                              Icons.menu,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 30,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          '16',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 100,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(
                                Icons.cloud,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 25.0,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 15.0),
                              Text(
                                'Raining',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 30,
                    top: 15,
                    left: 60,
                    right: 60,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Put on your coat, and don\'t forget the umbrella.',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 25,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(
                  color: kAccentColor,
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 30,
                    top: 15,
                    left: 30,
                    right: 30,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      DetailedCard(
                        header: 'HUMIDITY',
                        headerColor: kAccentColor,
                        text: '87%',
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      DetailedCard(
                        header: 'WIND M/S',
                        headerColor: kAccentColor,
                        text: '4,1',
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      DetailedCard(
                        header: 'FEELS LIKE',
                        headerColor: kAccentColor,
                        text: '18',
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just separate your UI based on different possible states. Then use `BlocBuilder` and check states. Finally render UI for respective state.

You can check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27EP04T824Y&t=1s)

Comment: I know that. But I'm confused where to place BlocBuilder. This UI should be for loaded state. It displays weather info. Should I place multiple BlocBuilders, for every piece of data I want returned, or should I place one BlockBuilder and return this whole UI ? What is better performance wise, to have multiple builders on different place, or to have one builder which renders the whole thing? Sorry for dumb questions, I'm learning flutter for like two months and state management got me hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely have multiple BlocBuilder. To make it simpler, let's take a look at this Counter example app.

I put this one wrapping a `Column` with 2 `Text` Widgets even though the only one supposed to be changing is the second `Text` Widget. (Not a good thing)

```
class CounterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Counter')),
       body: BlocBuilder<CounterBloc, int>(
         builder: (context, count) {
           return Center(
             child: Column(
               children: <Widget>[
                 Text(
                   'You have pressed this many',
                   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                 ),
                 Text(
                   '$count',
                   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                 ),
               ],
             ),
           );
         },
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this snippet, I put the BlocBuilder pricisely wrapping the only Widget that is changing on state changes. And if you ask `Where in my code should I put BLoC builder?` This approach is better because there won't be unnecessary Widget rebuilds happen.

```
class CounterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Counter')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pressed this many',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
            ),
            BlocBuilder<CounterBloc, int>(
              builder: (context, count) {
                return Text(
                  '$count',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And for `can I have more of them?`, absolutely.

```
class CounterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: BlocBuilder<CounterBloc, int>(
        builder: (context, count) {
          return AppBar(title: Text('$count'));
        },
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pressed this many',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
            ),
            BlocBuilder<CounterBloc, int>(
              builder: (context, count) {
                return Text(
                  '$count',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a source for unnecessary rebuilds ? Flutter is optimized and I doubt placing the Bloc builder at the top is enough to create a rebuild of every widget on change